# Node.js неправильно выдаёт файлы

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Есть html страничка, которую нужно отдать. В ней есть подключение js-файла. Сам сервер:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server listening port 3000');    
});
```

Но получается вот такое:

[image: 1]

Если заменить эту строчку

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});
```

на эту

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});
```

то в консоли выводит

> GET http://localhost:3000/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

хоть структура приложения и выглядит так:

[image: struct]

Если вручную вбить `http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js` — ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});
```

Означает, что на запрос '/' надо отдать один этот файл **/dist/index.html**.

А что делать с отсальными запросами сервер не знает.

Добавьте вот это

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));
```

Это будет означать, что нужно поискать файлы в директории **dist**

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно юзать функцию `render()` для рендеринга/отображения страницы.

```
const express = require ('express');
const path = require ('path');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../view'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.get('/index', (req,res)=>{
    res.render("index");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server start on port ' + 3000);

});
```

В папке `public` css-файлы, а в папке `view` все html-файлы, которые можно рендерить.
Структура проекта должна быть такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Больше можеш прочитать [тут](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/using-template-engines.html) и [тут](http://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#app.render)